# Accessory of table view cell not showing in iOS 9 and swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a simple table view and embed in navigation controller. I have selected a accessory type for cell and use a segue to the other view controller to show details of that cell. But accessory not showing. If i use this code

```
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
```

Then accessory shows but segue not working.

This is my code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = "test"

   // cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator


    return cell
}
```

Please tell me where is the problem.

Comment: Please show code for the segue. I have added a response below as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using something like this to perform the segue:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SEGUENAME", sender: self)
}
```

If so, adding

```
cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
```

should work fine.

Comment: Apparently the segue is a segue in the storyboard, not in code, so changing this to code should not be necessary.

Comment: Please give us more information. You are not telling us about how your project works.

Comment: You should connect a segue between the 2 view controllers. Then give that segue an identifier. Then perform that segue.

Comment: Yes. You understand my problem and give me the right solution. Thanks @penatheboss

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've hooked the segue in the storyboard to the accessory (the disclosure indicator). But a disclosure indicator is not a button, so that can never work (it is not tappable); and it is not what your users expect. Either:

- Hook the segue to the cell itself; or
- Use a tappable button accessory, such as an info button.

Comment: I have hook the segue to the cell. But same result

Comment: I assure you that the mere presence of a disclosure indicator will not break the ability of the cell to trigger a segue!

Answer (score 1):

You should create your segues between viewcontrollers.

Do not create segue from cell to viewcontrollers.

Then after you select a cell you should decide which segue you would like to invoke.